# Execute a part of that function only once, but the function itself multiple times. Python

Tags: python

I know the question seems very weird, but maybe this example can lay it out more clearly.

```
def entry_point():
  if list_already_exists:
     list.append(something)
  else:
     list = [something]
  run_program(list)

def run_program(list):
  for idx, value in enumerate(list):
     print(idx)
     time.sleep(value)
```

So `run_program` is the actual function which does everything(kind of like the driver code)
`entry_point` can be called many times even when `run_program` is under execution.

With the current approach, whenever I try to modify the `list`, `run_program` starts all over again from the beginning.

I don't want that. I want `entry_point` to execute `run_program` just once and next time I run `entry_point` to modify `list`, `run_program` shouldn't be interrupted, only the updated list should be passed to `run_program`.

**Intended output**

> first ever call to `entry_point()`
> should create a new list, lets assume `list = [1]`

> entry_point() --> run_program(list)
> output would be `1` and `wait` for 1 sec

> second call to `entry_point()`
> adds something to the already existing list. `list = [1,2]`

> meanwhile, after one second wait, `run_program(list)` would print `2` and `wait` for 2 secs

> So on and so forth...

Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: I feel like that's not the model you want - you just want `run_program` to run forever and check if there are value updates to (something). However, this is also just a toy demonstration you've given, what is the actual purpose for what you're doing?

Comment: yes exactly said. I just simplified it for this example purpose. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73363742/auto-iterate-through-the-queue-and-play-songs-discord-music-bot 
You can find the actual purpose in this link. I don't mean to create duplicate questions, but answering rate in discord.py tag area is very low.... so had to. Is that too complicated to achieve what you have suggested?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others that the behavior you described is more suited to listers, event emitters or threads. However, I am still unsure of the exact use case you need it for. Following is a simple implementation without any of the mentioned things - that satisfies the flow you mentioned. You can tweak it according to the need if it fits your constraints.

All calls to the **entry_point** also pass a index to the **run_program** function and hence the global list is updated and each time the correct value is chosen for the sleep function. Hope it helps to some extent.

```
import time

global val
val = 1
global lst

def entry_point():
    global val
    global lst
    try:
        lst.append(val)
    
    except:

        lst = [val]
 
    idx = lst.index(val)
    run_program(lst, idx)

    val += 1



def run_program(lst, idx):
    value = lst[idx]
    print(f'Index is {idx} and value is {value}')
    time.sleep(value)


entry_point()
entry_point()
```

Comment: this is an interesting approach, thanks for your inputs. and the exact use case of my question can be found here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73363742/auto-iterate-through-the-queue-and-play-songs-discord-music-bot
it'd be helpful if you can kindly look into that and provide your insights over there

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you need some kind of Thread to keep run_program executing while you modify the list in the entry_point function.

You can pass the list in a Queue and make the run_program function continue in the point it left the previous list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73363742/auto-iterate-through-the-queue-and-play-songs-discord-music-bot
If you can take a look at this question, I have already implemented a thread to keep it running, but doesn't work for some reason, maybe my implementation was wrong. Thanks..